# Using function pointer, but got warning makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

I got a problem that I want to use function pointer concept, but I in loop make me confuse.
I will try to describe my question clearly.

I want to create a template as read version function, that I can use getVersion API with differnt version function to get I want. 
e.g. Library_Version, Traffic_Version and so on.
Like this, getVersion(Library_Version), getVersion(Traffic_Version)..

I'm not sure that this method keyword is called function pointer.
If you know the currect keyword, please tell me.

Thanks for your reading and help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct XYZ_VERSION{
        int major;
        int minor;
        int build;
}xyx_Version;

int Library_Version(xyz_Version *pVersion){
        xyz_Version version = {0};

        version.major = 4;
        version.minor = 0;
        version.build = 3;
        *pVersion = version;
        return 666;
}
int getVersion( int(*f)(xyz_Version *pVersion)){
        xyz_Version *ppVersion;
        int message = (*f)(ppVersion);
        return message;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int res;
        res_Version pVersion;
        res = getVersion(Library_Version(&pVersion));
        printf("res:%d\n", res);
        return 0;
}
```

```
BUG:
linn@linn:~$ gcc -c funcPointer.c
funcPointer.c: In function ‘main’:
funcPointer.c:36:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘getVersion’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   36 |  res = getVersion(Library_Version(&pVersion));
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   int
funcPointer.c:27:22: note: expected ‘int (*)(xyz_Version *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct XYZ_VERSION *)’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   27 | int getVersion( int(*f)(xyz_Version *pVersion)){
```

Comment: Note that there is no "currying" in C.  You can't take a function accepting one argument, and somehow "package" it with a preselected argument such that it can be called later as if it were a function accepting no arguments.  The argument has to be passed in the code that actually makes the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
getVersion(Library_Version(&pVersion))
```

You're not passing a function pointer to `getVersion`.  You're *calling* `Library_Version` and passing the return value of that function to `getVersion`

This is also invalid:

```
    xyz_Version *ppVersion;
    int message = (*f)(ppVersion);
```

Because you're passing an uninitialized pointer to a function.

You want to change `getVersion` to take both a function pointer and the argument to that function and use them together:

```
int getVersion( int(*f)(xyz_Version *), xyz_Version *pVersion){
        int message = f(pVersion);
        return message;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
res = getVersion(Library_Version, &pVersion);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in the original code:

1. On line: `res = getVersion(Library_Version(&pVersion));` you are calling function `Library_Version`, but you actually want to pass in a pointer to call it later.
2. In `getVersion` you actually attempt to pass in `ppVersion`, which is an uninitialized pointer.  Instead, you should pass in a pointer provided from the caller.

The following should fix the problems that you are having.

```
    typedef struct XYZ_VERSION{
        int major;
        int minor;
        int build;
    }xyz_Version;
    
    int Library_Version(xyz_Version *pVersion){
        xyz_Version version = {0};
    
        version.major = 4;
        version.minor = 0;
        version.build = 3;
        *pVersion = version;
        return 666;
    }
    
    int getVersion( int(*f)(xyz_Version *pVersion), xyz_Version * pVersion){
    
        int message = (*f)(pVersion); // <-- Call function and used passed in pointer to return version.
        return message;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int res;
        xyz_Version pVersion;
        res = getVersion(Library_Version, &pVersion); // <-- Pass in pointer to function and pointer to object used to return version info.
        printf("res:%d\n", res);
        return 0;
    }
```